# css float not working in IE 7 or 8

Tags: html, css

This code show 3 columns in both firefox and chrome.
However when you load the page up in internet explore 7 or internet explorer 8, it will show each and every element vertically.

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

```
> <style> /* THREE COLUMNS */
> 
> ul.three-col {   overflow: hidden; }
> 
> ul.three-col le {   float: left;   width: 30%;   margin-right: 5%;  
> margin-bottom: 15px;   /* .edge below makes up for the overage */ }
> 
> ul.three-col le img {   margin-left: -2px;   margin-bottom: 7.5px; }
> 
> ul.three-col le.edge {   margin-right: 0; }
> 
> 
> </style>
> 
> 
> 
> 
> <ul class="three-col">
>     <le>
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/optimization.png">
>       <h4>Web Page Optimization</h4>
>       <p>another text block</p>
>      </le>
>     <le>
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/lower_costs.png">
>       <h4>Lower Costs</h4>
>       <p>another text block</p>
>     </le>
>     <le class="edge">
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/passionate.png">
>       <h4>Passionate Support</h4>
>       <p> another text block</p>
>     </le>
>     <le>
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/expert2.png">
>       <h4>Top Advertising Experts</h4>
>       <p>another text blockt</p>
>     </le>
>     <le>
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/constant_contact.png">
>       <h4>Constant Contact</h4>
>       <p>another text block</p>
>     </le>
>     <le class="edge">
>       <img src="http://example.com/images/bottom/targeted.png">
>       <h4>Targeted Traffic</h4>
>       <p> another text block</p>
>     </le>   </ul></div>
```

Comment: I think you have messed up the `<le>` element with the real `<li>` element. Chrome and Firefox is rendering a generic element but older versions of IE doesn't support anything else than real standard elements.

Comment: Are you going to tell us your desired outcome? And what have you done to resolve/research the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This `<le>` tag doesn't exist in HTML.
Either you've taken it from an incorrect resource, or just made it up, but you can't use it like this.

Browsers can do whatever they want with made-up tags, including totally ignoring their CSS rules.

**Perhaps you meant `<li>`** ("**l**ist **i**tem").

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are using an <le> Tag which is not an HTML Tag (you probably meant <li>)

The second problem you have is, that you give each li element a width of 30% but you also assign a margin of 5% to the right which leads to a total of 105%.

If you use the following css and replace the <le> with <li> it should work down to at least IE5

```
<style> /* THREE COLUMNS */

 ul.three-col {   overflow: hidden; }

 ul.three-col li {   float: left;   width: 25%;   margin-right: 5%;  
 margin-bottom: 15px;   /* .edge below makes up for the overage */ }

 ul.three-col li img {   margin-left: -2px;   margin-bottom: 7.5px; }

 ul.three-col li.edge {   margin-right: 0; }


</style>
```

And if you don't want a list-style (the small dots to the left that will appear) you can additionally use

```
ul.three-col { list-style-type: none;}
```